# Do we need to synchronize java HashMap gets if there is only one writer thread

Tags: java, hashmap, synchronization

I am maintaining an in-memory `HashMap` that stores list of `testUserIds` to their `emailId`.

```
HashMap<Integer, String> testUsers = new HashMap<>()
```

And there is just one background thread that reads additions/deletions to list of `testUsers` and performs the operations on this map. As there is only one thread writing to this map, I do not have to necessarily make it a synchronized map.

But there are multiple threads reading from this map. Do I need a `ConcurrentHashMap` if there is only one writer but multiple readers?

Comment: Does the one writer thread attempt to write at the same time the multiple reader threads are reading? Could the writer write why the reader(s) are iterating?

Comment: Writer Thread is writing at the same time as Reader Threads. Readers do not use Iterators. Readers only use map.get(key).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you should use `ConcurrentHashMap` (or synchronize your `Map` externally). Otherwise, if the writer thread is modifying the `Map` while any of the other threads iterates over the `Map`, you could get a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

From `HashMap`'s `Javadoc` :

> Note that this implementation is not synchronized. **If multiple threads access a hash map concurrently**, and **at least one of the threads modifies the map structurally**, **it must be synchronized externally**.

From `ConcurrentModificationException`'s Javadoc :

> **java.util.ConcurrentModificationException**
>
> This exception may be thrown by methods that have detected concurrent modification of an object when such modification is not permissible.
>
> For example, **it is not generally permissible for one thread to modify a Collection while another thread is iterating over it**. In general, the results of the iteration are undefined under these circumstances. Some Iterator implementations (including those of all the general purpose collection implementations provided by the JRE) may choose to throw this exception if this behavior is detected. Iterators that do this are known as fail-fast iterators, as they fail quickly and cleanly, rather that risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future.

Comment: I was going through your answer and , it incited one question in my mind, generally is it better idea to user ConcurrentHashMap over HashMap , as most of the applications uses the map the same way as described in the question???

Comment: @NiranjanKumar `ConcurrentHashMap` is less efficient than `HashMap`, due to the synchronization. Therefore I'd only use it when I need synchronization.

Comment: this is similar to classic Reader-Writer problem , yes you need to make it thread safe

Comment: @NiranjanKumar Most maps do not need to be synchronized. Most maps are only used by a single thread.

Comment: @Eran the Javadoc says `at least one of the threads modifies the map structurally`. Does that mean that if we are doing only updates (no addition/deletion) of the keys, ConcurrentHashMap will not be needed?

Comment: @robinkc What kind of updates is the writer doing? Is it replacing the value for an existing key with a new value?

Comment: Yes, in another application we need to update values for an existing key, again, with a single writer thread and multiple reader threads. Was wondering if we need ConcurrentHashMap there.

Comment: @robinkc It looks like using a HashMap shouldn't be a problem in this case (unless you are using a LinkedHashMap sorted by access order, which modifies the map structurally even when a key is not added/removed), but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, If you are working in a multi-threaded environment, then you have to consider synchronization otherwise unexpected data will be delivered.